# PHPExcel Remove Rows By ID

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, object-oriented-analysis

I would like to remove a certain row by using Employee ID.
I used PHPExcel Library to read the excel worksheet.
I have this code below, it does delete a row but insert also an empty row.
Can't seem to figure out.

```
<?php 
/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . './Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . './Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("EmpTest.xlsx");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$highestrow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();

for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestrow; $row++) {
    if ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$row) == $_GET['ID']){ 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row);
    break; 
    } 
}
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('EmpTest.xlsx');

header("Location: index.php");
exit; //done.. exiting!
?>
```

When I hit the "Delete" button this will be the result.
[Delete an employee result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyO4w.jpg)

This will be done on my excel worksheet. You will see an empty row inserted.
[Excel worksheet result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcnrk.jpg)

Comment: What row number are you actually trying to delete? This code will delete a row that didn't even exist until the code was executed (`$row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()+1;`)

Comment: And the image doesn't show what is being done to the Excel file, just that your on-screen display is showing an empty first row

Comment: I want to delete the row of a certain employee by using his ID as key for deletion. So that when I hit the "Delete" button the row will be deleted from the excel worksheet.

Comment: Then you need to start by identifying the row number that contains that ID, not a row that's after the highest row that exists in the worksheet.... but I don't have your worksheet, I don't know what the employees ID is in the worksheet

Comment: You're also playing pick-a-mix with $_GET, $_REQUEST and $_POST... how is the employee id value being sent to this script?

Comment: Please refer from here http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcnrk.jpg

Comment: I try to fix the code but no luck for me. Any help please?

Comment: How are you sending the row to delete through to the script? Is it a field in a POST request? Is it in the URL?

Comment: In the URL.
Please refer to this code.

echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="remove.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'">Delete</a>';

Comment: http://localhost/CRUD/remove.php?ID=1.0

This would be the sample URL when I hit the "Delete" button.

Comment: `for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestrow; $row++) { if ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$row) == $_GET['ID']) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row); break; }
}`

Comment: The code still do the same thing.
It will delete a certain row but also insert an empty row in the last row of the worksheet. :-(

Comment: @MarkBaker shouldn't it be `getCell('A'.$row)->getValue() == $_GET['ID']`...?

Comment: @ImClarky - true, my bad.... it's the value that should be tested, not the cell itself

Comment: Though I'm still concerned that all it's doing is blanking the row rather than delting it; that's not the behaviour that I observe in test

Comment: @MarkBaker I guess so.  I'm also thinking that the problem is the function itself. The removeRow() doesn't delete the entire row but blanking rather.

Comment: But if the problem was in the removeRow() function, I'd expect to see the same behaviour in my test environments, and I'm not..... this is a standard PHPExcel function (quite a complex one) designed to shuffle the rows/columns and adjust all formulae in the worksheet so as not to leave blanks; and that's exactly what I'm seeing in my tests

Comment: Now my problem is that how can I delete this empty rows leave by the removeRow() function?

Comment: @JoviOrmillada - If possible, could you delete someone in the middle of your employees table, say `Anita`, and then post a screenshot of the excel result. As Mark says, the `removeRow()` function doesn't blank a row, it removes it and bumps the underneath data up (which is also what I'm seeing in my tests), therefore I'm having trouble understanding what your problem is.... ***haven't had my morning coffee***

Comment: Here's what I get when I try to delete  "Anita" using the delete button.
The function does delete the Anita's row and the row next to Anita.

Please refer here for the screenshot.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/AjNhE.jpg